# Proving imaginary number lies parallel to the real axis.

Tags: complex-numbers

Define $$z \equiv 2e^{i\theta}$$We are to obtain the imaginary and real parts of $$w=\frac{z-2}{z+2}$$ I ended up getting $w=\frac{i\sin\theta}{1+\cos\theta}$ I got this by multiplying by $\frac{e^{-i\theta}+1}{e^{-i\theta}+1}$ I suspect this is wrong as it failed to provide a valid solution for the next part which says to prove $\ln{w}$ will always lie on a line parallel to the real axis. I got: $$\ln{w} =\ln{\frac{\sin\theta}{1+\cos\theta}} + i\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+2\pi n\right)$$ For $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ Which implies $\ln{w}$ lies perpendicular to the real and parallel to the imaginary. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I have calculated $w$ and the result is the same. I guess that it is said $\ln w$ is on a line parallel to the real axis for any  $\theta\in (0,\pi)$.

Comment: That is encouraging! The questions says "Hence calculate $\ln{w}$ and deduce that this complex number always lies on a line which is parallel to the real axis in the Argand plane." But it gives the range of $0<\theta<\pi$. And $\ln\frac{\sin\theta}{1+\cos\theta}$ is not necessarily zero across this range, which is required to answer the question.

Comment: Note that the imaginary part of $\ln w$ is the same once you fix $n$. So, all numbers $\ln w$ when $\theta$ runs between $0$ and $\pi$ are on the same line parallel to the real axis.

Comment: Indeed! Many thanks for the help. I think I misunderstood the questions assuming, $\theta$ to be constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should double check your definition of $w$ after plugging in the definition of $z$; I found:

$w = i\tan\frac{\theta}{2}$.

In any case, this isn't the big issue! You simply misinterpreted your result of $\ln w$. If you think of the real and imaginary parts of $\ln w$ as an $(x,y)$ coordinate, you'll find:

$\left(\ln\left|\tan\frac{\theta}{2}\right|,\frac{\pi}{2}+2\pi n\right)$

This has a constant $y$ coordinate and a varying $x$ coordinate---this is by definition a line parallel to the $x$, or equivalently the real axis!

So, ultimately, you had the right mathematical answer all along, just the wrong interpretation.

Comment: Ah yes! I think I took $\theta$ to be a constant and $n$ to be the variable as opposed to the other way around! Many thanks for the help!

Comment: $w=i\tan \frac{\theta}{2}$ is not far from $\frac{i\sin \theta}{1+\cos \theta}$.

Comment: A quick sketch on a calculator shows they're the same no?